# php reverse order of fetched array

Tags: php

I have very basic php question. I am fetching data from database and printing them with some styling row by row. The problem is that these data represent news and I would like them to be printed in reverse order (the last row I fetch should be printed first). I am not sure if I can fetch the whole table at once and them apply the reverse function (I tried it but it didnt work).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
                include 'dbconnect.php';
                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news") or die(mysql_error()); 

                while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
                {
                echo '<article><h3> '.$info['subject'].'</h3><div id="date">'.$info['date']. '</div>';
                echo '<p>'.$info['news']. '</p></article>';

                } 
?>
```

I tried something like this:

```
$data = [];
array_push($array, $info);
```

inside the while loop and then printing it but it didnt turn out to work. Thanks for any answer!

Comment: How about `array_reverse`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Avoid mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It fixes the ordering, but 'SELECT *' is a very bad practice. While it the code may seem to work with mysql_fetch_assoc(), using it with mysql_fetch_array() is downright silly.

Answer (score 3):

You should to that directly in sql and not afterwards in php:

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC
```

You should also switch to PDO (or mysqli) as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC"
```

You can use this, if you have an ID for every news.

Answer (score 0):

array_reverse() function of PHP or `ORDER BY`id`(or time/date column) DESC` in mysql query

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC")
```

I believe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
$data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```